# How to change the application theme by clicking radio button according to the users choice

Tags: android-actionbar

How to change the application theme, title bar color and background color for all the activities by clicking radio button according to the users choice

Answer (score 0):

```
//Pseudo code snippet is given
    Let me assume the first page of android app might be having different set of radio as blue,green, red etc., 
each color might have defined in the style.xml with the required background,foreground,font color etc.,
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:orientation="vertical">    
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_blue"        android:layout_width="wrap_content"        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        android:text="@string/pirates"        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>    
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_red"        android:layout_width="wrap_content"        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        android:text="@string/ninjas"        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    </RadioGroup>

//In utility method
    public static void savePreferences(String key, String value, Context context) {

        SharedPreferences SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }
//in that page radiobuttononchange
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

// Is the button now checked?

boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked



switch(view.getId()) {

case R.id.blue:

if (checked)
//store the value in sharedpreferences
savePreferences("preference","blue",getcontext());
break;

case R.id.red:

if (checked)
savePreferences("preference","red",getcontext());


break;

Intent nextScreen = new Intent(

context,

Form.class);

startActivity(nextScreen);


}

}

//In next activity
//Oncreate
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String themeName = pref.getString("preference", "Theme1");
if (themeName.equals("blue")) {
    setTheme(R.style.blue);
} else if (themeName.equals("red")) {
    setTheme(R.style.red);
}.....
setContentView(R.layout.activity_some_layout);
}
```